# How to show localization messages with parameters in Spring 3 / Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I'm using Spring 3 and Thymeleaf to make some webpages and I am lost as for how to show messages like this:

welcome.message=Hello {0}, welcome!

and then replace {0} with the user name inside thymeleaf tags:

```
<h1 th:text="#{welcome.message}">Welcome Placeholder</h1>
```

I'm not even sure if {0} is the right syntax for the bundle message.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

You can use

```
#{welcome.message(${some.attribute})}
```

where `some.attribute` would be the value to use when replacing `{0}`.

You should be able to comma separate the values between the `()` to add more values to be used.

Answer (score 33):

You can even use a calculated message key as a parameter:

```html
<p th:text="#{messages.msg1(${param1})}"></p>
<p th:text="#{messages.msg2(${param2},${param3})}"></p>
<p th:text="#{messages.msg3(#{${param4}})}"></p>
```

Above, the parameter of [msg3] is a message key [#{key}] where key is itself calculated [${param4}]. The benefit is that you can insert internationalized calculated fragments in an internationalized message.

Answer (score 9):

If you need to pass an array of parameters where you don't know the size of the array then you can use:

```html
<p th:text="${#messages.msgWithParams(messageKey, messageParams)}"></p>
<!-- or -->
<p th:text="${#messages.msgOrNullWithParams(messageKey, messageParams)}"></p>
```

https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#messages-1