# How can I set field name?

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

My thymeleaf code:

```
Your favorite number: <input type="text" th:field="*{xy}"/>
```

My messages.properties:

```
  required={0} is required
  typeMismatch.java.lang.Integer={0} is not a number
```

When the user doesn’t fill this field, or types bad data, this message has displayed automatically:

```
  xy is required
```

or

```
  xy is not a number
```

But I would like to set the field name „Your favorite number” instead of „xy”, so I would like to display these messages when error:

```
  Your favorite number is required
```

or

```
  Your favorite number is not a number
```

How can I set field name for `{0}`?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20789441/how-to-show-localization-messages-with-parameters-in-spring-3-thymeleaf) you can specify the message parameters after the message key. So you should be able to do something like:

```
<div th:text="#{${error}('Your favorite number')}">Error message</div>
```

This will fill the `{0}` parameter with whatever you pass it. `error` is a variable containing the validation message (presumably from a call to `hasErrors` or similar).

You could even move your field name into your message properties, in which case you just need to nest another message:

```
<div th:text="#{${error}(#{field.xy})}">Error message</div>
```

And in `message.properties`:

```
field.xy=Your favorite number
```

This would then insert the contents of the `field.xy` message into the placeholder `{0}` of the validation message.