# Thymeleaf sytax of expression for multiple parameters

Tags: thymeleaf, ognl

[The documentation](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#messages) says that you can use parameters in your strings like so:

```
home.welcome=¡Bienvenido a nuestra tienda de comestibles, {0}!

<p th:utext="#{home.welcome(${user.name})}">
  Welcome to our grocery store, Sebastian Pepper!
</p>
```

And indeed, that is working for me.

However, it also says that "several parameters can be specified, separated by commas."

However, I cannot figure out the syntax for multiple parameters.

My source string is something like

```
home.welcome=Welcome to {0} store, {1}!
```

And I have tried the following expressions

```
1. #{home.welcome((${store.name}),(${user.name}))}
2. #{home.welcome(${store.name}, ${user.name})}
3. #{home.welcome(${store.name, user.name})}
4. #{home.welcome(${store.name}),(${user.name})}
```

Which all give TemplateProcessingException: Could not parse as expression,
except #4 which gives ??home.welcome(${store.name}),_en??

What is the correct syntax of the expression for loading two parameters into a template string?

I found this answer, but it doesn't work. It suggests I do #2 above

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27501557/2153273

Comment: What is the entire stack trace?  Are you sure that `store` isn't null, and you're not getting an error about that?

Comment: #2 was correct, I just had a mismatched } in the source string