# Is there a way to pass String.format to thymeleaf template?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am building thymeleaf template and I must pass to it some String with parameters, like `The value equals %s`. The thing is that a message can be any so I can not just set Message/Externalizing text in my `thymeleaf.properties`.

I have tried something like this

```
    <td th:text="#{(${myObject.stringFormatMessage})(${myObject.param})}"></td>
```

But it ends up with `??The value equals %s_eng_ENG??`. 
I also changed `%s` to `{0}` but the result is almost the same. 
I can not parse this string before passing to my template because `myObject.param` has to be bold/colored.
Is there any way to do it - pass String.format instead of setting externalized text in my `.properties`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20789441/how-to-show-localization-messages-with-parameters-in-spring-3-thymeleaf

Comment: This solution works when I set `welcome.message` in my `.properties` with any message, not when I pass it from my application

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use it like this:

```
<td th:text="${T(java.lang.String).format(myObject.stringFormatMessage,myObject.param)}"></td>
```