# Thymeleaf: placeHolders in property files

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a SpringBoot app. with Thymeleaf, with this property file:

```
signup.form.error.file.too.big=File ${fileName} is too Big
```

on the contoller:

```
if (Objects.nonNull(fileExceedsTheconfiguredMaximum)) {
            hasErrors = true;
            model.addAttribute("fileName", fileExceedsTheconfiguredMaximum.getOriginalFilename());
        }
```

on the template:

```
 <li th:if="${fileToBig}"  th:text="#{signup.form.error.file.too.big}" />
```

but I see this on the browser:

```
File ${fileName} is too Big
```

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20789441/how-to-show-localization-messages-with-parameters-in-spring-3-thymeleaf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make a couple of changes to your code.

Change message property as per below:

```
signup.form.error.file.too.big=File {0} is too Big
```

And the other change would be in a thymeleaf template file:

```
 <li th:if="${fileToBig}"  th:text="#{signup.form.error.file.too.big(${fileName})}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting the filename with a `#{fileName}` won't help. You can add the file name with the `${fileName}`.

```
<li th:if="${fileToBig}" th:text="#{signup.form.error.file.too.big(${fileName})}" />
```

[Alternative answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20789795/2039546)