# How to show localization messages with parameters as links in Thymeleaf

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am aware from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20789441/how-to-show-localization-messages-with-parameters-in-spring-3-thymeleaf) that you can add parameters to messages like this:

```
<p th:text="#{messages.msg1(${param1})}"></p>
```

However, I need to be able to make this parameter a link. Is this possible?

For example:

```
# messages.properties
msg1=Hello, my name is {0}!

# messages_x.properties
msg1={0}, my name is!
```

**Hello, my name is [Kim](http://google.com)**

**[Kim](http://google.com), my name is**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible by using `th:utext` and adding the link in the translation. Might not be ideal, but it should work:

```
msg1=Hello, my name is <a href="...">{0}</a>!
```

And:

```
<p th:utext="#{messages.msg1(${param1})}"></p>
```

(Note the `utext` instead of `text`, see [documentation](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#unescaped-text))

Comment: Coincidentally, that's exactly how I managed to do it! Yes, not ideal with `utext` but it's not user input so it'll do.

Comment: Ok, please mark the answer as correct so others know the question is answered.